# SQL - return deleted rows

Tags: sql, select, sql-delete

I would like to combine a SELECT which returns rows and a DELETE which deletes a subset of the rows I selected?

Is this possible?

Comment: What RDBMS? Also can you provide a sample showing the desired results?

Comment: Not in the same query it isn't.

Comment: SQL server. The results would be the same as doing a SELECT on some of the rows returned would no longer exist in the database

Comment: Under MS SQL Server, you can use: `DELETE ... WHERE ... OUTPUT DELETED.*`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a SELECT statement that returns all the candidates, just change SELECT to DELETE with OUTPUT DELETED.*.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbl1
 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tlb1.col = tbl2.col
 INNER JOIN tlb3 on tbl2.anothercol = tbl3.somecol
 WHERE blah blah blah
```

Can become:

```
 DELETE tbl1 OUTPUT DELETED.*
 FROM tbl1
 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tlb1.col = tbl2.col
 INNER JOIN tlb3 on tbl2.anothercol = tbl3.somecol
 WHERE blah blah blah
```

Comment: I get an Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'. Am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: It should work with SQL 2005.  You might have to put it into a table variable, like this:  DELETE
FROM TestTable
OUTPUT Deleted.ID, Deleted.TEXTVal INTO @TmpTable

Comment: Yes, I updated the reply but it gave me an awaiting peer review message. The INTO clause is optional. :-)

Comment: The syntax would be RETURNING * in psql.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using pgAdmin 3 and for some reason the syntax in the accepted answer didn't work for me (not sure why, the error was: **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETED"**)

What worked for me was:

```
DELETE 
 FROM tbl1
 where column1 = value
 RETURNING *;
```

For more information see the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-delete.html)